# In apache spark how we can remove data from file once spark reads it

Tags: apache-spark

I am using custom spark receiver for spark streaming. In the receiver, I am reading text from the file and make its RDD.

The problem is, that data remains in file and spark custom receiver reads it again. So I want to remove data from the file to avoid duplication once spark reads it.

The receiver function looks like this

```
private void receive() {

    try {
        List<String> blocks = new ArrayList<>();

        while (!isStopped()){
            JavaSparkContext sc = spark.getSparkContext();
            JavaRDD<String> lines = sc.textFile("src/dummy2.csv");
            blocks  =  lines.collect();
            store(blocks.iterator());
            blocks.clear();
        }
        // Restart in an attempt to connect again when server is active again
        restart("Trying to connect again");
    } catch(Throwable t) {
        // restart if there is any other error
        restart("Error receiving data", t);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you writing new data to the file (updating) it? That would cause Spark to re-read it.

Comment: @Shaido i am not updating file. the data in file is static.

Comment: Can you add yuor code here?

Comment: @Shaido code added in description

Comment: Spark streaming receiver is to read streaming data for example from kafka or sockets. Why are you using it to read a file ? Also you are reading the file in the loop and will get the same data, even if you remove the data after first read, the receiver will continue reading empty file.

Comment: @MrSpark so it means i should use spark job rather the spark streaming?

Comment: In this case, where you just need to read data from file, yes use spark job.

Comment: @MrSpark Thanks alot